# What lifecycle method should a network request be put into if I want it to execute every time that activity comes into view?

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit2

The question is fairly self explanatory. If I want my app to make a request every time the user sees a particular activity, which method e.g. onCreate, onStart, etc., be put into so that it is always executed every time the user views the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

I think you are looking for `onResume()` method. When the activity enters the Resumed state, it comes to the foreground, and then the system invokes the `onResume()` callback. This is the state in which the app interacts with the user. The app stays in this state until something happens to take focus away from the app. Such an event might be, for instance, receiving a phone call, the user’s navigating to another activity, or the device screen’s turning off.

When the activity moves to the resumed state, any lifecycle-aware component tied to the activity's lifecycle will receive the `ON_RESUME` event. This is where the lifecycle components can enable any functionality that needs to run while the component is visible and in the foreground, such as starting a camera preview.

When an interruptive event occurs, the activity enters the Paused state, and the system invokes the onPause() callback.

If the activity returns to the Resumed state from the Paused state, the system once again calls `onResume()` method. For this reason, you should implement `onResume()` to initialize components that you release during `onPause()`, and perform any other initializations that must occur each time the activity enters the Resumed state.

Comment: Very detailed answer. I presume that when an activity loses focus for whatever reasons, the likes of all variable values are kept, or would I be mistaken in saying that?